# curses: Straight line with last color at the bottom of the window in windows cmd

Tags: python, cmd, curses, python-curses

### problem

When I run a curses program via windows `cmd.exe` that outputs colored text I get an unselectable line on the bottom of the window.
How can I remove it?

### example

```py
import curses

def main(stdscr):
    curses.init_pair(1, 200, 100)
    stdscr.addstr("test ", curses.color_pair(1))
    stdscr.refresh()
    stdscr.getch()

curses.wrapper(main)
```

[image: image of the line]

### cause

The problem is that curses thinks that the terminal is smaller and resizes the window resulting in this line at the bottom.

If I do

```py
curses.resize_term(10, 10)
```

a second line appears on the side and becomes way bigger; I guess this is the way cmd handle smaller terms

### solution

to fix that bug I should use another terminal or say to the user that if he is on Windows he should not go on the cmd but use something like `PowerShell` or `Windows Terminal`

Comment: There's not enough information.  Running in `cmd.exe`, that **might** be PDCurses.  The legal range for the foreground/background colors is likely 16.

Comment: Try [restoring the terminal to its previous graphics mode](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) using `curses.endwin()` after text output. You may also want to check the color pairs used are valid

Answer (score 1):

I would start with a `stdscr.clear()` (if you need to clear the screen)

But you should add a `stdscr.refresh()` between your addstr() and the getch()

And as said by T3ERR0R, don't forget the `curses.endwin()` before the end of your script.

Comment: Thanks, `stdscr.refresh()` does sometimes make the line smaller (when terminal size is changed during run)